# How to make a smoke for blizzard effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation

I have a quick question if someone of you can help me would be great.
[image]

If you see I have this picture, in my final render I want to obtain the same smoke effect like in the right side, but from some reason... doesn't matter what I'm trying to do, every time it's looks almost the same like in the left corner of the picture.
Have anyone of you and idea how can I obtain the same effect like in the right side.